# Finding the rate of change of a relation at $x=1$

Tags: calculus

$$x+y^2-y=1$$  If I want to find the rate of change with respect to $x$ at $x=1$, why do the following give different results?

Method A, set $x=1$ so we now have $y^2-y=0$.  If I take the derivative of this with respect to x, I get $2yy'-y'=0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}(2y-1)=0 \implies y = \frac{1}{2}$

Method B, straight up finding the derivative nets me $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{1-2y}$$ When $x=1$ I know that $y=0$ or $y=1$, this gives me a different answer than the first method.  But logically, shouldn't they both give me the same answer if I want to find the derivative(s) at $x=1$?

EDIT: Corrected to $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: The first method is wrong,  if you want to find rate of change, you do not first "freeze" $x$. And setting the result equal to $0$ is for no reason. The second is almost right, and there are two possible values of $y$, with two different slopes. For some reason you wrote $\frac{dx}{dy}$ instead of $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: @turkeyhundt When you implicitly differntiate the first equation? I did $1+y^2-y=1 \implies y^2-y=0$.  Also, I only care about the rate of change at $x=1$.  Does this still count as "freezing x"?

Comment: Yes.  you can't plug in a value for x before differentiating.  And I deleted my comment because you did get the correct dy/dx.  I just had the numerator and denominator multiplied by -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method is wrong.  If you want to find rate of change, you do not first "freeze" $x$. You freeze  *after* finding the derivative. And setting the result equal to $0$ is for no reason.

The second is right, and there are two possible values of $y$, with two different slopes.